# How to get test history

Tags: testing, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-api

I have many builds with failed tests.
I learn one test and want to find last build, where this test was succesfully.

How I can find this build or how I can get test results history?

Answer (score 0):

If as a post-build step you are publishing your test results, you should be able to go to the job page and see the test results graph. If you are looking for the last build where all tests passed, you can click on "enlarge" under the graph. You will then see a high level view of all the builds from which you should be able to see the last build where all tests passed.

If you are looking for the last time a particular test passed, you can click on the latest build in the test results graph, drill down to the particular test you are interested in, and then click the previous build button until you find a build where that test passed.

If you aren't publishing your test results, you may be able to write some groovy code to scan through your build results, but beyond that I don't know of a way to find what your looking for without publishing test results in your post-build.